# What does ArrayIndexoutofBoundsException mean here?

Tags: java, string

Given a string, print the number of alphabets present in the string.
Input:
The first line of input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.Each test case contains a single string. 
Output:
Print the number of alphabets present in the string.

This is a question i have been trying to solve this question on eclipse but it keeps throwing ArrayIndexoutOfBoundsException in line 7 of my code. I tried understanding what i've done wrong but i have not been able to. 
Could some one please explain whats wrong here . I have attached the code.

```
public class solution {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "baibiasbfi" ;
        int count =0; 
        for(int i=0;i<=s.length();i++){
            char[] a= s.toCharArray();
            if(a[i]>='a'&& a[i]<='z'||a[i]>='A'&&a[i]<='Z')
                count++;}
    System.out.println(count);  
    }
}
```

Comment: to avoid this exception use i<s.length()

Comment: Basically what ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException means is that you're trying to access a position of your array `a` that's beyond access.

In this case, your string `baibiasbfi` has 10 characters which means that you can access it from position 0 to 9.

When you're doing `i <= s.length()`, and since `s.length` is equal to the size of the array which is 10, you're trying to access the position 10 of the array which is beyond reach.

To solve it, remove the `=` from your condition `i <= s.length()` and you'll have your problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
i <= s.length();
```

in your `for loop` should be:

```
i < s.length();
```

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown:

> to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal
>   index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the
>   size of the array.

Comment: thank you so much ............ it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In java, arrays are from `0` to `length-1`. You are using your loop compare it with `i<=s.length()`. This means your loop is giving back the length of the array. This gives a `ArrayIndexoutofBoundsException`.

Replace your loop with:

```
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
```